# Sobolev embedding theorem on Manifolds

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I'm looking for a reference which states the Sobolev embedding theorems on Riemann manifolds for **fractional** Sobolev spaces.

The references I know either don't deal with fractional spaces, or don't deal with manifolds.